# Not mangling names renders music unplayable on Windows 10 Samba

Tags: files, windows, samba

I have set up a very basic file server on linux. I used the Samba setting
`mangled names=no` to disable to make sure the files are legiable under Windows, but once I do that, all the wav files I have stored in the folder are unreadable/unmovable/unplayable.

I cannot use different files, the script I am using can only generate .wav files.

An example of the file name would be `2017-07-24 12:54.wav`, which otherwise gets mangled as `2BB0Y9~4.WAV`.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/381538/243257 for an example of mangling.

Comment: Whoops. It is a date time string of format y-m-d h:m:s

Comment: "2017-12-24 12:23.wav"

Comment: The other question isn't really a duplicate, but the new answer there covers this