# Samba share folder name incorrectly displayed on linux machine

Tags: fedora, samba, cinnamon

I have a NAS server running OMV 5 which I use to store personal data (documents, photos, videos, etc.). I use Samba to share the data from the NAS and I am running Fedora 33 on the client that I use to access the shared data.

The issue that I have is that folders named `aux` on the NAS appear as `AHY9U3~9` on the Fedora client, see example below
[image]
The working directory in the left tmux panel is on the client whereas in the right panel the working directory is on the NAS. I find it bizarre that I can access the folder on the client using either the weird name or the correct name the folder has on the NAS.

I stumbled upon this "error" when I was trying to synchronize data between the client and the NAS using software run on the client. I have a bunch of folders named aux scattered throughout the folder hierarchy and the sync software flagged a difference for them when the issue is actually how their names are mapped on the client.

I don't know what causes the issue and, most importantly, how to fix it. I am also wondering if there are other folder names that are erroneously mapped on the client side.

Please find below software version information for both the client and the server
Server samba version: Samba version 4.9.5-Debian
Client samba version: Version 4.13.12
Client info:

- Kernel version - 5.14.13-100.fc33.x86_64
- Cinnamon version - 4.8.6

I found some related posts, see below, however, I would reckon that `aux` is a valid filename according to samba rules, isn't it?

1. [samba how to display files with colon in their names?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299130/samba-how-to-display-files-with-colon-in-their-names)
2. [Not mangling names renders music unplayable on Windows 10 Samba](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381538/not-mangling-names-renders-music-unplayable-on-windows-10-samba)

EDIT:
Below is the global section and the respective share section from smb.conf,

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = %h server
dns proxy = no
log level = 0
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
logging = syslog
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
encrypt passwords = true
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = no
unix password sync = no
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY
guest account = nobody
load printers = no
disable spoolss = yes
printing = bsd
printcap name = /dev/null
unix extensions = yes
wide links = no
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
use sendfile = yes
aio read size = 16384
aio write size = 16384
time server = no
wins support = no
multicast dns register = no
# Special configuration for Apple's Time Machine
fruit:aapl = yes
```

```
[test]
path = hidden-path/test/
guest ok = no
guest only = no
read only = no
browseable = yes
inherit acls = yes
inherit permissions = no
ea support = no
store dos attributes = no
vfs objects = 
printable = no
create mask = 0664
force create mode = 0664
directory mask = 0775
force directory mode = 0775
hide special files = yes
follow symlinks = yes
hide dot files = yes
valid users = 
invalid users = 
read list = 
write list =
```

EDIT2:
I wouldn't have thought `aux` to be a reserved word, but yes, it is, see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file. Thanks to @Ricky for pointing it out. Now, I just need to change the name of my folders.

Comment: ```aux``` is indeed a valid name according to Samba rules.  Do you have "strange" configuration options in your /etc/samba/smb.conf file? You probably already know you can reset the samba config running this: ```omv-mkconf samba```. (Make sure you backup the file before.) Probably you want to show the [global] section of your config file and also the config of the share?

Comment: @LincolnP I updated my message to include the global and the share section from the config file.
I didn't know about resetting the samba confing file. I don't however have the omv-mkconf utility installed on my NAS. Could you please elaborate on what the utility does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aux` is a reserved word in DOS/Windows. Attempting to access the file will fail via any "normal" means:

```
T:\>dir \\.\t:\aux
10/31/2021  08:50 AM                 0 aux
           1 File(s)              0 bytes

T:\>dir t:\aux
File Not Found
```

My version of samba (3.0.10) is quite old, so it doesn't mess with the name at all. (short name and long name are "aux")